What equipment is needed to raise the side of a pergola that is attached to a house by 1 1/4”
We have a pergola built on our deck and attached to our house. Almost complete. Have discovered that the side of pergola attached to the house needs to be raised by about 1 1/4” for a pitch that matches the deck. When we pull the side screen down there is excess puckered screen fabric on the house side when the screen latches in on the front pergola leg.  What is the best way to do this without having to deconstruct existing structure. The roof of the pergola has louvers.

Why does the pitch need to match the deck? The deck should be almost flat with just a slight pitch to shed water. Raising the house side will increase the difference in pitch. Your question makes no sense.

I reworded the question.

The instructions assume the pergola is being built on a level surface.
We hired someone to construct this and we are stalled with this error. I’m trying to help find solutions. Frustrated does not adequately convey our experience. Also, from elsewhere I have read that there should be a slight pitch on the ‘roof’ to assist with rain water run off. I’m not an expert, just a fairly desperate home owner.

Wouldn't cutting the screen to match the decking be easier?

The roof seems to have the right slope.  Just wondering if the screen mounts can be adjusted, so the screen comes down straight, instead of at an angle.

It’s a retractable screen that has a base and latches. It’s a whole unit by itself.

You can still shim the screen mounting far more easily than you can rebuild the roof. This is an X/Y question; you have jumped to asking how to implement a particular (suboptimal) solution rather than asking how to solve the real issue
